# Resources for learning Russian: should we have it at all?

Tags: discussion, resources

I'd like to create a single question, thus putting resource questions off topic from now on, in the Main Site, using the structure I used in the [Chinese one](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/1120/resources-for-learning-mandarin-chinese).

The question is: **do you want it?**

Resource questions are going to be closed anyway in case they are too broad, since this is the standard rule, but if we made this question, we'd have a compromise.

You can find two answers below, **vote up** the one you agree with. In order for it to be easier to judge, even if you vote down, I'll consider only the upvotes. So only the absolute voting.

**In a week**, I'll check the situation and see if the community wants it. So, vote! If you have something to say, feel free to comment this question or the relevant answer.

Note: My vote is not present because I proposed the question and I cannot vote but I vote yes.

Even one exceeding vote wins.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### I vote yes.

(Upvote if you agree)

Voting this answer, I agree with the creation of this resources question.

Answer (score 0):

### I vote no.

(Upvote if you agree)

Voting this answer, I disagree with the creation of this resources question.