# Resources for learning Russian: should we include only free material?

Tags: discussion, resources

The community [said yes to a question with resources for Russian](https://russian.meta.stackexchange.com/q/190/71), but do we want to allow free material only or commercial too?

Vote on the answer below.

- **Vote up** to allow free material only.
- **Vote down** to allow both free and commercial material.

Comment: [Note](http://meta.russian.stackexchange.com/q/89/109) as soon as you get started...

Answer (score -2, accepted):

### Vote on this answer!

**Voting up**, you want the question to allow free material only. Commercial material will be forbidden.

**Voting down**, both free and material will be included (with proper labeling, stating what answers are free and what ones are commercial).

Comment: ABBYY Lingvo is mostly commercial, apart from the online dictionary, but it is nevertheless a very good resource.